# Changing the video stream of the front camera

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

an interesting problem has arisen, is there any way to send my own video stream to the front camera of the phone (I have PocoM3 Pro), for example, I open some messenger or my own camera and instead of the stream from the front camera, my preloaded video is coming, maybe there are ready-made solutions or ideas how to implement it.

To be honest, I haven't tried anything, and I don't have many ideas on this, so I want to find out from the experts